# Update 2 Solidity contract variables with one transaction

Tags: javascript, solidity

How do I chain two contract updates together?

This following code works for individually updating each of them, but I have to approve the first update in Metamask, then wait for it to finish before the other update asks to be confirmed in Metamask :

```
      await vaultcontract.methods.update7Day([update7day]).send({from: account}).then(function(receipt){
        document.getElementById("7dayupdated").innerText = "updated";
      });
     
      await vaultcontract.methods.update30Day([update30day]).send({from: account}).then(function(receipt){
        document.getElementById("30dayupdated").innerText = "updated";
      });
```

How can I do both with one transaction?

Comment: Try if [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
Promise.all([
    vaultcontract.methods.update7Day([update7day]).send({from: account}),
    vaultcontract.methods.update30Day([update30day]).send({from: account})
]).then( _ => {
    // variable name is _ (underscore) because you don't use it
    document.getElementById("7dayupdated").innerText = "updated";
    document.getElementById("30dayupdated").innerText = "updated";
});
```

Comment: That works ok, thanks. It's better than waiting for one to finish before being allowed to confirm the next transaction. I assume you can't roll the two transactions into one and just pay more gas for the single transaction?